# journalctl --user giving "No journal files were found."

Tags: debian, systemd

If I do `systemctl --user status <myservice>` I get the status of the service together with some recent log output. If I do `journalctl --user -u <myservice>` I get "No Journal files were found.". This applies to multiple user services. This does not apply to non-user/system services.

Debian sid.

Answer (score 4):

You want `journalctl --user-unit <myservice>`.

The `--user` parameter to `journalctl` is a filter to restrict it to units running under the current user, but it still distinguishes between user and system units. I personally don't understand the design choice of why `-u` doesn't automatically select the user unit when `--user` is enabled, especially when it does so for `systemctl`, but there it is.

Comment: Now it doesn't say no files found, but it does say "No entries", because the log time is only the last ~30 minutes. Every so often the begin-end window will move forward.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to enable persistent storage, because [per-user journals are not supported when storing logs in /run tmpfs](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2744). This is done with `Storage=persistent` in */etc/systemd/journald.conf*.

If you’d prefer not to do that, the only alternative I know is to add your user to the systemd-journal group, or (in Debian and perhaps Ubuntu) the adm group.