# journalctl --user -u myservice "No journal files were found", for a specific user

Tags: users, d-bus, systemctl, sssd, journalctl

**Problem:**

systemd user units journalctl output display "No journal files were found." This only happens for the one sss user I am testing with, all local users seem to work fine. EDIT: sss does not seem to be the issue. Just this user is the problem. Exact command and output:

```
$journalctl --user -u myservice
No journal files were found.
```

**system env**

- RHEL 8.4
- systemd 239 (239-45.el8_4.3)
- kernel: 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64

**Troubleshooting:**

I already read these posts and tried troubleshooting found within each:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783134/systemd-user-journals-not-being-created
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193518
- [Why does journalctl say "-- no entries --"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288243/why-does-journalctl-say-no-entries)
- [journalctl --user giving "No journal files were found."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439597/journalctl-user-giving-no-journal-files-were-found)

I have tried the following:

- Rebooting.
- Redeploying the host OS.
- Tried creating a local user to test with.
- Made sure to login to all newly created local user account I am working with directly with SSH or terminal initially before continuing testing. Also tested sshing to the sss user account in question which I am able to.
- Restarting journalctl services (`systmectl restart systemd-journald.service`)
- Made sure /etc/systemd/journald.conf `Storage=persistent`. But also tried auto, and volatile, no change with any.
- added `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)` in ~/.bashrc for the local user and the user in question. Then sourced the file.
- Confirmed linger is enabled.
- Noticed that this problem is only happening one specific user on the box. Created new users, and this problem does not happen.
- User account in question has a different uid from the gid/groups. However I tested adjusting a newly created account with a different uid from its gid/groups, adjusted the ~/.bashrc for the new uid, rebooted, and that account works showing the correct journalctl output.
- User account in question appears to be an sss user.
- Confirmed the user's d-bus channel is running with `ps`, I see the user is running `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user`
- I am able to run other `systmectl --user` commands as the user in question. I can check status, start, stop, restart the user service.
- When I run `journalctl --user`, here is the output:

  ```
  $ journalctl --user
  No journal files were found.
  -- No entries --
  ```
- When I run `journalctl --user --verify`, here is the output:

  ```
  $ journalctl --user --verify
  No journal files were found.
  ```
- I did all the above on another box where the sss user is also built, problem follows the user account.
- I found journalctl output! but its in /var/log/messages (the default location for journalctl output to syslog for rhel systems). Wonder why it shows there but not for the --user area?
- I checked `systemctl status user.slice --no-pager` and see the correct user slices for each uid with the correct services, `systmectl --user status myservice` shows the correct slice as well. However if I check `ls /var/log/journal/<number>` I do not see the `user-<UID>@UUID.journal` listed for the user in question.

This problem appears to only happen for the user I am testing with which was built with sss. I am not able to remove or rebuild this user as I do not manage sss on this system.

Why does this specific sss user `journalctl --user` output not appear but local user's do? What am I missing here? Not sure how else to troubleshoot this issue, any recommendations?

**EDIT:** well it does not seem to be sss related. I deployed my own AD server, integrated kerberos and SSSd, built a user, and journalctl works fine for them.

At this point I have no idea why this user's journalctl will not work, any recommendations  for troubleshooting would be helpful!

**EDIT2:** I found journalctl output for the --user service does show in `/var/log/messages` but this can only be accessed by root.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem!
The user in question had a UID/GID that was < 1000.
I adjusted the UID/GID to "1111", logged off and back in, and the journalctl immediately started working!

After reading [this post](https://systemd.io/UIDS-GIDS/) it made realize maybe journalctl was doing something that would not allow it to work with systemd --user units that it perceived as used for system users.